# Managing a field in Active Directory (that I can't find)

Tags: powershell, vbscript, active-directory

Before I got into my position someone had created a field for our users called PCN, This held some information for where the user was located and what PC they where assigned to. This is all fine and good but they use this .vbs to edit this field in AD.

```vb
Dim objEmployeeNumber
Dim objSelectedUser
Dim strNewEmployeeNumber
Set objEmployeeNumber = Wscript.Arguments
Set objSelectedUser = GetObject(objEmployeeNumber(0))
strNewEmployeeNumber = InputBox("Employee PCN: " & objSelectedUser.employeeNumber & vbCRLF _
  & vbCRLF _ 
  & "To enter a new Employee PCN," _
  & " type it into the text box" _
  & " below and click OK.")
if strNewEmployeeNumber <> "" then objSelectedUser.Put "employeeNumber",strNewEmployeeNumber
objSelectedUser.SetInfo
WScript.Quit
```

I am trying to streamline all the AD editing the Helpdesk does into a single PowerShell script since it would run from our ticketing software but I have no idea how to add this Employee PCN information in. (Relatively new to PowerShell as well)

Can anyone make sense of this to know how I could add this information in using PowerShell instead of this .vbs?

Comment: Are you using Get-AD (the built in methods) or QAD Tools?

With QAD there is a switch to properties (-AllProperties perhaps?) and the you can simply `$user = Get-Qaduser -SamAccountName jsmith -GetAllProperties; $User.EmployeeNumer (it might be .EmployeeId

Comment: I am using Get-AD methods. I will research QAD Tools and see if that can help me

Comment: Get-AD methods probably has the same or similar concepts, it's just when I was doing AD and PowerShell I found I much preferred QAD and thus remember a lot more.

Comment: You where right, I just did Get-ADUser (my Samaccountname) -properties * | Select *

Comment: and it showed me all properties, Now it appears my hunch from that .vbs code is true and it is called EmployeeNumber. Now How do i edit that? Shouldn't i be able to do something like Set-ADUser -identity (samaccount) -EmployeeNumber 123123 ? (that doesnt seem to be working)

Comment: Nevermind I just screwed up a bit there, it worked out great! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Derived with assistance from Austin French
I used the Get-ADUser (Account) -properties * | Select *
To show all the properties and found it, I was then able to add it like all my other items. Thanks for your assistance Austin French!